# Is it better to reuse SqlCommand when executing the same SQL query several times?

Tags: c#, refactoring, readability

When querying the database with the same query but different parameters, is it better to:

- do it in a single using,
- or to create two separate queries?

**Example of a single using:**

```
using (SqlCommand addProduct = new SqlCommand(@"insert into [Products].[Products] ([Name], [Price]) values (@name, @price)", sqlConnection))
{
    // Insert the first product.
    addProduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "Product 1");
    addProduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", 41F);
    int countAffectedRows = addProduct.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Debug.Assert(countAffectedRows == 1, "Wrong number of rows affected.");

    addProduct.Parameters.Clear();

    // Insert the second product.
    addProduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "Product 2");
    addProduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", 49.9);
    countAffectedRows = addProduct.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Debug.Assert(countAffectedRows == 1, "Wrong number of rows affected.");
}
```

**Example of the same code using two separate queries:**

```
// Insert the first product.
using (SqlCommand addProduct = new SqlCommand(@"insert into [Products].[Products] ([Name], [Price]) values (@name, @price)", sqlConnection))
{
    addProduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "Product 1");
    addProduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", 41F);
    int countAffectedRows = addProduct.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Debug.Assert(countAffectedRows == 1, "Wrong number of rows affected.");
}

// Insert the second product.
using (SqlCommand addProduct = new SqlCommand(@"insert into [Products].[Products] ([Name], [Price]) values (@name, @price)", sqlConnection))
{
    addProduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "Product 2");
    addProduct.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", 49.9);
    int countAffectedRows = addProduct.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Debug.Assert(countAffectedRows == 1, "Wrong number of rows affected.");
}
```

In my opinion, the second one must be preferred, because:

- it makes it more clear to see where the SQL command is disposed and how much times it is executed,
- it is easier to modify if, in future, for some reason, the query must be modified in one case, but not in the other,
- the first one makes it easy to forget the `SqlCommand.Parameters.Clear()`.

On the other hand, the first sample is more explicit about the fact that the query is the same in both cases, and that only parameters change.

Comment: You are right, the second solution is more clean. You should not reuse the same SqlCommand unless you are going to do a hyper-mega performance tuning.

Comment: Maybe you should place the insert code into a seperate function and call it twice.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's very little benefit to reusing the command instance, unless you're planning to call [Prepare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare.aspx).

If you're going to run the command many times (dozens or more), then you probably want to create the command, prepare it, execute it in a loop, and then dispose it. The performance gains are significant if you're running the command many times. (You would add the parameters once, though, before you prepare -- not delete and re-add them every time like you're doing in your first code sample. You should change the parameters' *values* each time, not create new parameters.)

If you're only going to be running the command a handful of times, performance isn't an issue, and you should go with whichever style you prefer. Creating the command each time has the benefit that it's easy to extract into a method so you don't repeat yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If by "better" you mean "clearer" or "cleaner", use separate SqlCommand objects.  This will also assist with refactoring your code down the road.

If by "better" you mean "faster", re-using the SqlCommand will eliminate the chance that a new SqlConnection will be created (vs. being pulled from the connection pool).

Comment: Both constructor calls in his second example use an already opened connection.